# MySql container stuck at "Restarting..." on Dokku

Tags: mysql

I tried to create a new mySql database on my Dokku container.
Using

```
dokku mysql:create bookmarks
```

The container has been created, but it seems it is unable to start.
The command

```
# dokku mysql:list
NAME               VERSION       STATUS      EXPOSED PORTS  LINKS
bookmarks          mysql:5.6.26  restarting  -              -
```

I am unable to stop, restart or destroy this container.

```
# dokku mysql:destroy bookmarks
 !     WARNING: Potentially Destructive Action
 !     This command will destroy bookmarks MySQL service.
 !     To proceed, type "bookmarks"

> bookmarks
-----> Deleting bookmarks
       Deleting container data
 !     Service is already stopped
       Removing container
Error response from daemon: Conflict, You cannot remove a running container. Stop the container before attempting removal or use -f
Error: failed to remove containers: [dokku.mysql.bookmarks]
```

I also tried to reboot the entire server, without any success.
To me, it seems like something went wrong during the creation of this container that makes the system unable to start it. The problem is that at the same time I am unable to stop or restart it, and being unable to stop it I cannot remove it and start from scratch.

```
# dokku mysql:stop bookmarks
 !     Service is already stopped

# dokku mysql:restart bookmarks
 !     Service is already stopped
-----> Starting container
       No container exists for bookmarks
-----> Please call dokku ps:restart on all linked apps
```

The error message says something about "forcing" the process, but I can't find anywhere how to use it.
Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you in advance,
Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally with the help from people from DigitalOcean I've been able to stop and destroy that faulty container.

Here is what I did:

1. Check Docker processes running

`docker ps -a`

2. Identify the process that is causing the problem, in my case it was:

`8549c8ec4e53        mysql:5.6.26                     "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   17 hours ago        Restarting (1) 2 hours ago   3306/tcp            dokku.mysql.bookmarks`

3. Kill the **Docker** process

`docker kill 8549c8ec4e53`

4. Remove the container from Dokku

`dokku mysql:destroy bookmarks`

Hope this answer helps others having similar problems.